# Find the volume of an object...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Find a volume of an object enclosed with $x=y^{2}+z^{2}$ and the $x=6$ planes.

Can I use cylindrical coordinates here? If so, then what will the $r$ be? The radius of the enclosing circle at the top is $\sqrt{6}$, so it would be:

$$0<r<\sqrt{6}$$
$$0<\phi<2\pi$$
$$r^{2}<x<6$$
Unfortunately as far as I know the radius should be measured from the $(0,0,0)$ point, so it's wrong. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $r$ in this case is the orthogonal distance from the $x$-axis, so your bounds are fine (though they aren't actually strict). Then you need only evaluate $V=\iiint_S\,dV,$ noting that $dV=r\,d\phi\,dx\,dr$ (whether through the Jacobian or some other means).

If we were using *spherical* coordinates, then the radius $\rho$ is the distance from the origin, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the fact that this solid is formed by revolving the region bounded by the curves $x=y^2$ and $x=6$ around the x-axis, so that the volume (using the disc method) is given by
$V=\int_0^6 \pi (\sqrt{x})^2dx=\pi\int_0^6x dx=18\pi.$

Another way to do this is to notice that the volume is the same as that of the solid bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=6$ (by interchanging x and z), so then using polar coordinates gives 
$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{6}}(6-r^2)rdrd\theta.$